# adding message to batch history in Kofax capture 10

Tags: capture, kofax

I want to add an history entry in Batch properties history tab when the operator opens the batch. Currently the logging is happening when the operator is closing or suspending the batch.

Comment: Please can  any one let me know how can I modify the History in Batch properties in KC 10

Comment: You cannot - Batch Properties history tab basically just shows a history of the modules that have taken place in the workflow of the batch.  The best you can do is log activity elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this. Kofax infrastructure handles these loggings internally for auditing reasons. A log event consist of a DURATION so that means the beginning AND the end of the operation must exist. This is not an event log but rather module usage log.
If you want finer grained control for user events, then you must write your logging mechanism. Kofax gives great API for that with the ModuleTypeLibrary API. See help and example source codes on how to hook onto events like the batchOpening event.